# Homework Java Overriding

Tags: java

I have Super class RECTANGLE with 2 variables and a Child class SQUARE with 1 variable. I am using class Square to inherit the getArea() method and overide it fine. Eclipse editor gives me an error in my SQUARE class, "super(width, length);". LENGTH variable has an error that can be fixed with making it static in the RECTANGLE class, that's not what I desire I guess. My homework requires that class SQUARE has a constructor with 1 variable to multiply by  itself. What is the logical error in my code?

```
public class Rectangle 
{

double width, length;

Rectangle(double width, double length) 
{
    this.width = width;
    this.length = length;
}

double getArea() 
{
    double area = width * length;
    return area;
}   

void show() 
{
    System.out.println("Rectangle's width and length are: " + width + ", " + length);
    System.out.println("Rectangle's area is: " + getArea());
    System.out.println();
}
}


public class Square extends Rectangle
{
double width, length;

Square(double width) 
{
    super(width, length);
    this.width = width;
}

double getArea() 
{
    double area = width * width;
    return area;
}   

void show() 
{
    System.out.println("Square's width is: " + width) ;
    System.out.println("Square's area is: " + getArea());
}
}


public class ShapesAPP 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Rectangle shape1 = new Rectangle(5, 2);
    Square shape2 = new Square(5);
    shape1.show( );
    shape2.show( );
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
Square(double width) 
{
    super(width, width);
    //this.width = width;
}
```

A `Square` is a rectangle with all sides of equal length.

You get the error because you're attempting to use `length` which wasn't yet initialized.

Also, you needn't have members `width` and `length` in `Square`. You already have them in the base class. So a better revised version would be:

```
public class Square extends Rectangle
{
    Square(double width) 
    {
        super(width, length);
    }

    double getArea() 
    {
        double area = width * width;
        return area;
    }  



    void show() 
    {
        System.out.println("Square's width is: " + width) ;
        System.out.println("Square's area is: " + getArea());
    }

}
```

Comment: `double width, length` and `this.width = width` shouldn't be necessary inside `Square` - the former is inherited, the latter is taken care of by Rectangle's constructor. No?

Comment: Why does that work? I thought the super class rectangle has to keep the same variable names.

Comment: the `local` declaration of `width` is redundant and confusing as well; it **hides** the super class instance it doesn't over-ride it.

Comment: @badboy don't duplicate members.

Comment: Luchian, I was looking for the why and you explained it well. "You get the error because you're attempting to use length which wasn't yet initialized." That's what I didn't understand.

Comment: You can't subtract members in a subclass. It will have both `width` and the `length`. If you use `super(width, width)`, you automatically get the correct `getArea` by inheritance. `super(width, length)` is an error since there is no local `length`, and the member `length` is uninitialised at that point.

Answer (score 4):

You should have the constructor like this:

```
Square(double width) 
{
    super(width, width);
}
```

Also you should eliminate the following line in the Square class: `double width, length;`